# PROTRACTOR: How to Run Few Spec on firefox browser and few spec on Chrome browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

I have 10 test cases, In which first 8 test cases should run in Chrome browser and next 2 test cases should run in Firefox browser.

I have tried below code: in **conf.js**

```
  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters-master');

  var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
  var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

  exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',      //framework Used
seleniumPort: 4444,         // selenium port address
    specs: ['./Spec/Master.spec.js'],      //Spec -> consists of test suite/ test cases
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {                   //jasmine framework details
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 260000,
    print: function() {}
},

    multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'args':['incognito','--start-maximized'],  // this line is for maximize the window and incognito view

    prefs: {
        'profile:managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1
    },
    exclude: ['./Spec/RestCall/ShowGeoLocation.js'],

},
    {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        specs: ['./Spec/RestCall/ShowGeoLocation.js']
        // Spec files to be excluded on this capability only.
        //exclude: ['spec/doNotRunInChromeSpec.js'], //YOUR SPEC NAME THAT YOU WANT TO EXCLUDE/SKIP
    }],
maxSession:1,


onPrepare: function (config_) {                  // before starting the actual TC execution, setup the things we define here
    require('./Data/waitReady.js');
    //browser.manage().window().maximize();

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: false,
        savePath: './Reports/JunitXMLprotractor-result/',
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));


}

};
```

**./Spec/Master.spec.js'** has:

```
       var showGeoloca = require('./RestCall/ShowGeoLocation');

       describe('REPORTING USER ROLE - ',function () {
    Reporting.start();         contains actual spec

       });
       describe('Rest Call - ',function () {
       showGeoloca.start();          contains actual spec
       });
```

**In Simple, Reporting.start() should run in Chrome browser. ShowGeoloca.start should run in Firefox browser**.

Note: Inside Each Spec code, I didn’t specify any new instance of creating new browser

But didn't work as expected.

How can we achieve this? Can we create a new instance of Firefox browser on the go? (while a test case is running)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Most importantly, I wanted to see the actual `specs` values, not the sample ones. Directory structure showing how your tests are organized would also help a lot.

Comment: pls check now @alecxe . I dont like you to confuse by posting more code. Simply put, we are giving info about browser run for Spec in common in Conf.js (mutliple capabilities). My Question: Where to specify for spec 1 run   against Chrome and Spec 2 run against firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the getCapabilities method for the browser global. In general this would work something like the following if you went down this path. Personally, I'd consider how you might break this down into multiple test scenarios without conditional logic guiding the expected outcome.

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
  if (caps.get('browserName') === 'chrome') {
    // do something related to chrome
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Cheree. where to specify the above code you said. My Question is **Where and how to tell protractor to run few test case on CHROME and few testcase on FIREFOX**

Comment: Keasav, I think you'd have a couple options to get closer to that outcome.
1) Break out browsers with lots of specific scenarios/workflows into their own config files. Then you'd have the option of using either filepath filters or regular expression filters against test names to limit what is run.
2) Break out browser-limited test cases into their own files. Use "specs" or "exclude" in the capabilities object to include or exclude as appropriate.